# I can't get my Javascript to copy text to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, clipboard

Need a little help from someone if that's possible.

I'm crafting a drop-down DIV for my website which allows users to press a button and have the HTML character code for a variety of symbols copied to the clipboard. This is not yet in its final format - I've just created a simple HTML page to test the functionality.

The issue is that it doesn't work! I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Here's my HTML which combines a basic in-line stylesheet and the Javascript:

```js
function copyFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("charInput");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select(); 
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

   /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Text Formatting</title>
<style>
body {
background-color: #309bbf;
}
.chardisp {
width: 40px;
text-align: center;
}
.charhead {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
}
.charbutt {
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 3px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: black;
outline: 0;
}
.charbutt:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><p class='charhead'>FORMATTING</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&lt;b&gt;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&lt;b&gt;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&lt;i&gt;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&lt;i&gt;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&lt;u&gt;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&lt;u&gt;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='<b>[ ... ]</b>' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\"><b>[ ... ]</b></button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&lt;br&#47;&gt;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&lt;br&#47;&gt;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><p class='charhead'>SYMBOLS</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&trade;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&trade;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&reg;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&reg;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#161;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#161;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#191;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#191;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#223;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#223;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&amp;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='$quot;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&quot;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&pound;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&pound;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&euro;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&euro;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#36;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#36;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#188;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#188;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#8531;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#8531;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#8532;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#8532;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#189;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#189;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#190;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#190;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#58;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#58;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#59;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#59;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#9834;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#9834;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#35;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#35;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#47;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#47;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><p class='charhead'>ACCENTED CHARACTERS</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#192;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#192;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#193;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#193;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#194;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#194;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#195;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#195;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#196;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#196;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#224;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#224;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#225;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#225;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#226;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#226;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#227;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#227;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#228;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#228;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#199;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#199;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#231;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#231;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#200;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#200;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#201;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#201;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#202;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#202;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#203;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#203;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#232;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#232;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#233;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#233;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#234;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#234;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#235;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#235;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#204;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#204;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#205;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#205;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#206;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#206;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#207;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#207;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#236;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#236;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#237;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#237;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#238;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#238;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#239;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#239;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#210;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#210;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#211;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#211;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#212;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#212;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#213;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#213;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#214;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#214;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#242;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#242;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#243;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#243;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#244;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#244;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#245;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#245;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#246;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#246;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#217;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#217;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#218;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#218;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#219;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#219;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#220;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#220;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#249;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#249;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#250;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#250;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#251;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#251;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#252;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#252;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#221;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#221;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#159;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#159;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#253;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#253;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#255;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=\"copyFunction\">&#255;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help with this would be HUGELY appreciated. I know it's something simple but not being very good with Javascript, I don't know where to start!

Comment: You are using the same id for every button?

Comment: `id` should be unique for each element

Comment: Three problem by just looking at it 
 1) onclick event is not firing use  copyFunction()
  2) Same id for each element 
  3) select() is not a function

Comment: copyText.select();  copyText.setSelectionRange will only work for input element not for buttons 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element ID's should be unique.

However to copy the get the button value you need to change the onclick to an example of the following

```
<td class='chardisp'><button value='&lt;b&gt;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick="copyFunction(this)">&lt;b&gt;</button></td>
```

This will allow the function to get the element's attributes.

The function will need modified also to suit, you will need to look further into how you are working the copyText variable to work for you.

Example:

```
    function copyFunction(element) {
        let elementValue = element.value
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(elementValue);
    }
```

To better implement this solution, you could invoke a window onload event listener and look for all buttons associated within your table.

To proceed on this route give your table an identifier, in this example I gave `#clipboardTable`. This will then allow use to use the `querySelectorAll` to add the click event listener for our buttons and allow for cleaner code within the HTML document, thus allow for removal of the `onclick="copyFunction(this)"` being repeated over all the buttons manually.

Window event listener and click event listener for buttons

```
    window.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
        // Find all buttons
        let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#clipboardTable button");
        buttons.forEach(button => {
            // Add event listener to each button
            button.addEventListener("click", event => {
                copyFunction(event.target)
            })
        })
    })
```

The copy function may remain the same as completed previously.

See this working snippet to prove concept.

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1252'>
<title>Text Formatting</title>
<script>
    // Window on load event listener
    window.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
        // Find all buttons
        let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#clipboardTable button");
        buttons.forEach(button => {
            // Add event listener to each button
            button.addEventListener("click", event => {
                copyFunction(event.target)
            })
        })
    })


    function copyFunction(element) {
            let elementValue = element.value
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(elementValue);
    }
</script>
<style>
body {
background-color: #309bbf;
}
.chardisp {
width: 70px;
text-align: center;
}
.charhead {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
}
.charbutt {
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid white;
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 3px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: black;
outline: 0;
}
.charbutt:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table id="clipboardTable" border='0'>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'><p class='charhead'>FORMATTING</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='<b>...</b>' class='charbutt' >&lt;b&gt;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='<i>...</i>' class='charbutt' >&lt;i&gt;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='<u>...</u>' class='charbutt' >&lt;u&gt;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='<b>[...]</b>' class='charbutt' ><b>[...]</b></button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='<br/>' class='charbutt' >&lt;br&#47;&gt;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'><p class='charhead'>SYMBOLS</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;trade;' class='charbutt' >&trade;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;reg;' class='charbutt' >&reg;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#161;' class='charbutt' >&#161;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#191;' class='charbutt' >&#191;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#223;' class='charbutt' >&#223;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;amp;' class='charbutt' >&amp;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;quot;' class='charbutt' >&quot;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;pound;' class='charbutt' >&pound;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;euro;' class='charbutt' >&euro;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#36;' class='charbutt' >&#36;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#188;' class='charbutt' >&#188;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#8531;' class='charbutt' >&#8531;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#8532;' class='charbutt' >&#8532;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#189;' class='charbutt' >&#189;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#190;' class='charbutt' >&#190;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#58;' class='charbutt' >&#58;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#59;' class='charbutt' >&#59;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#9834;' class='charbutt' >&#9834;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#35;' class='charbutt' >&#35;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#47;' class='charbutt' >&#47;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'><p class='charhead'>ACCENTED CHARACTERS</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#192;' class='charbutt' >&#192;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#193;' class='charbutt' >&#193;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#194;' class='charbutt' >&#194;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#195;' class='charbutt' >&#195;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#196;' class='charbutt' >&#196;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#224;' class='charbutt' >&#224;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#225;' class='charbutt' >&#225;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#226;' class='charbutt' >&#226;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#227;' class='charbutt' >&#227;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#228;' class='charbutt' >&#228;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#199;' class='charbutt' >&#199;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#231;' class='charbutt' >&#231;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#200;' class='charbutt' >&#200;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#201;' class='charbutt' >&#201;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#202;' class='charbutt' >&#202;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#203;' class='charbutt' >&#203;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#232;' class='charbutt' >&#232;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#233;' class='charbutt' >&#233;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#234;' class='charbutt' >&#234;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#235;' class='charbutt' >&#235;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#204;' class='charbutt' >&#204;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#205;' class='charbutt' >&#205;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#206;' class='charbutt' >&#206;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#207;' class='charbutt' >&#207;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#236;' class='charbutt' >&#236;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#237;' class='charbutt' >&#237;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#238;' class='charbutt' >&#238;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#239;' class='charbutt' >&#239;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#210;' class='charbutt' >&#210;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#211;' class='charbutt' >&#211;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#212;' class='charbutt' >&#212;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#213;' class='charbutt' >&#213;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#214;' class='charbutt' >&#214;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#242;' class='charbutt' >&#242;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#243;' class='charbutt' >&#243;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#244;' class='charbutt' >&#244;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#245;' class='charbutt' >&#245;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#246;' class='charbutt' >&#246;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#217;' class='charbutt' >&#217;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#218;' class='charbutt' >&#218;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#219;' class='charbutt' >&#219;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#220;' class='charbutt' >&#220;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#249;' class='charbutt' >&#249;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#250;' class='charbutt' >&#250;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#251;' class='charbutt' >&#251;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#252;' class='charbutt' >&#252;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#221;' class='charbutt' >&#221;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#159;' class='charbutt' >&#159;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#253;' class='charbutt' >&#253;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#255;' class='charbutt' >&#255;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'><p class='charhead'>INPUT TEST</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'><textarea style='width: 100%'></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Awesome. Now I can use the <button> tag as well. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly  define the onlick function properly and instead of the getting the element by id pass the element as reference to the function this will remove the burden of assigning id to each element and  also remove the unnecessary code.
Lastly navigator.clipboard.writeText returns a promise so it should be used properly otherwise its error prone (i.e. it will work the first time but will throw an error if you will try to copy another text)

```
<script>
function copyFunction(e) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.value).then(function() {
  /* clipboard successfully set */
}, function() {
  /* clipboard write failed */
});

}
</script>

<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><p class='charhead'>FORMATTING</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><input type="button" value='&lt;b&gt;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)></input></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&lt;i&gt;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&lt;i&gt;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&lt;u&gt;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&lt;u&gt;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='<b>[ ... ]</b>' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)><b>[ ... ]</b></button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&lt;br&#47;&gt;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&lt;br&#47;&gt;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><p class='charhead'>SYMBOLS</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&trade;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&trade;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&reg;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&reg;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#161;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#161;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#191;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#191;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#223;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#223;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&amp;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='$quot;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&quot;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&pound;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&pound;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&euro;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&euro;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#36;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#36;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#188;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#188;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#8531;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#8531;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#8532;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#8532;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#189;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#189;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#190;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#190;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#58;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#58;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#59;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#59;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#9834;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#9834;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#35;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#35;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#47;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#47;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><p class='charhead'>ACCENTED CHARACTERS</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#192;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#192;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#193;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#193;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#194;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#194;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#195;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#195;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#196;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#196;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#224;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#224;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#225;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#225;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#226;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#226;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#227;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#227;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#228;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#228;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#199;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#199;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#231;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#231;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#200;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#200;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#201;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#201;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#202;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#202;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#203;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#203;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#232;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#232;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#233;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#233;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#234;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#234;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#235;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#235;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#204;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#204;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#205;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#205;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#206;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#206;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#207;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#207;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#236;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#236;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#237;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#237;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#238;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#238;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#239;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#239;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#210;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#210;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#211;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#211;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#212;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#212;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#213;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#213;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#214;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#214;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#242;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#242;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#243;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#243;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#244;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#244;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#245;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#245;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#246;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#246;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#217;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#217;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#218;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#218;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#219;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#219;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#220;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#220;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#249;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#249;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#250;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#250;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#251;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#251;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#252;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#252;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#221;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#221;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#159;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#159;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#253;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#253;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&#255;' id='charInput' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#255;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. That was a real face-palm moment! You're a star. Works like a dream. Thank you, in fact, to all those who replied. I needed a little shove in the right direction and that's exactly what I got!

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank all those who replied. It was a real face-palm moment when I realised just how badly I'd got it wrong!

In the end, I opted for Aidan's answer because it allows me to format the button with the actual character whilst giving the value of the HTML code I need copied to ensure that it's compatible with the PHP it's being fed into. For my particular issue, a button tag far outshines an input tag in this regard.

Here's the fully revised code so that should anyone else need something similar, they don't need to ask such a stupid question again!

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1252'>
<title>Text Formatting</title>
<script>
function copyFunction(element) {
        let elementValue = element.value
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(elementValue);
    }
</script>
<style>
body {
background-color: #309bbf;
}
.chardisp {
width: 70px;
text-align: center;
}
.charhead {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
}
.charbutt {
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid white;
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 3px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: black;
outline: 0;
}
.charbutt:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table border='0'>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'><p class='charhead'>FORMATTING</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='<b>...</b>' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&lt;b&gt;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='<i>...</i>' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&lt;i&gt;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='<u>...</u>' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&lt;u&gt;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='<b>[...]</b>' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)><b>[...]</b></button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='<br/>' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&lt;br&#47;&gt;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'><p class='charhead'>SYMBOLS</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;trade;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&trade;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;reg;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&reg;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#161;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#161;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#191;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#191;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#223;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#223;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;amp;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&amp;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;quot;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&quot;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;pound;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&pound;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;euro;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&euro;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#36;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#36;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#188;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#188;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#8531;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#8531;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#8532;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#8532;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#189;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#189;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#190;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#190;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#58;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#58;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#59;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#59;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#9834;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#9834;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#35;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#35;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#47;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#47;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'><p class='charhead'>ACCENTED CHARACTERS</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#192;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#192;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#193;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#193;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#194;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#194;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#195;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#195;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#196;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#196;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#224;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#224;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#225;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#225;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#226;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#226;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#227;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#227;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#228;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#228;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#199;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#199;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#231;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#231;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#200;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#200;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#201;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#201;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#202;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#202;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#203;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#203;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#232;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#232;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#233;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#233;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#234;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#234;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#235;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#235;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#204;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#204;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#205;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#205;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#206;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#206;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#207;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#207;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#236;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#236;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#237;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#237;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#238;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#238;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#239;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#239;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#210;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#210;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#211;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#211;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#212;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#212;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#213;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#213;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#214;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#214;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#242;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#242;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#243;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#243;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#244;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#244;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#245;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#245;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#246;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#246;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#217;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#217;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#218;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#218;</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#219;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#219;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#220;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#220;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#249;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#249;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#250;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#250;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#251;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#251;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#252;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#252;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#221;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#221;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#159;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#159;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#253;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#253;</button></td>
        <td class='chardisp'><button value='&amp;#255;' class='charbutt' onclick=copyFunction(this)>&#255;</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'><p class='charhead'>INPUT TEST</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'><textarea style='width: 100%'></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```